# using html5 websockets to bypass firewall TCP policy

Tags: websocket, firewalls, malware

I've read that html5 enables opening tcp sockets from the client side in its "websocket" feature.

Firewalls as I recollect may be configured to block tcp connections initiated from "the outside" by looking for SYN packets, but utilizing this html5 feature enables a simplistic bypass to this policy.

Am I missing something here? Who will monitor those implicit open socket calls?
It appears that this behavior is a "reverse tcp shell" served for free...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, websocket connections are initialized from javascript which gets executed by the web browser on the client. That means typical websocket connections are outbound connections, not inbound connections. Inbound websocket connections would only be possible when the host runs a websocket *server*. A normal browser will usually not do this. And even when the host runs a websocket server for some reason: a properly configured firewall in a usual client network, can, should and will prevent this.

Second, websockets are not normal TCP sockets. They use a custom framing protocol on top of TCP. That means that a websocket connection can only be opened to a service which understands the websocket protocol. So even though the websocket API can be used to make the user (try to) connect to any remote host, they will be unable to make them use any service not intended for use via websockets.

Third, this is not a "remote TCP shell", because the websocket only lives in the javascript engine of the web browser and in the context of the currently visited HTML document. It does not give the website the user is visiting any more rights to do stuff on the local machine than it wouldn't already have. Sure, it gives the javascript application the ability to communicate with remote servers, but there were already plenty of ways to do this, like AJAX.

So what possible abuse potential remains?

As an owner of a malicious website I could spread a javascript which makes the user connect to a websocket server and performs some malicious activity on it. I could use this to turn my visitors into spam zombies to spam some websocket-based application by someone else. **But** websocket has a build-in feature to protect against this. The users webbrowser sends the URL of the website with every websocket connection. That means a service can easily ignore any connections which do not originate from a known URL.

For further information, I recommend the [RFC-6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) which describes the protocol itself and [the W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) for the Javascript API in web browsers.

Comment: Re "That means that a websocket connection can only be opened to a service which understands the websocket protocol" and your second last para, Yes but couldn't that be abused? There's nothing stopping you from firing a websocket connection at a nonwebsocket port searching for loopholes isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier You could of course do that, but it is unlikely to do anything useful. Every websocket connection uses a different, randomly-generated 32bit masking key which is not exposed to the javascript application which created the socket. The whole payload data is XORed with that key. So any data you send over the websocket will arrive as random garbage. The HTTP headers might be interpretable for the endpoint, but if you want to test its response to a HTTP header, you could just do an XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets are not plain TCP sockets, but offer a behavior similar to TCP sockets inside a HTTP tunnel. To actually use them to connect to arbitrary ports you have to have some server side backend which will make "real" TCP connections to the requested port from the WebSocket.

Apart from that this question is better asked at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip, would've +1 it but I'm still a n00b so I have no reputation...